# PANDAS converting variables to annual frequency when I don't want it to

Tags: pandas, date, frequency

I have some Pandas code for loading .csv files into DataFrames and it has the unfortunate result of converting my monthly and quarterly variables to annual frequency, when I want quarterly frequency.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


s1 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Tim Peterson\Documents\Tom\Rocky\WTISPLC.csv", index_col=0,parse_dates=True)
s2 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Tim Peterson\Documents\Tom\Rocky\CCUSMA02AUM618N.csv", encoding = "ISO-8859-1", engine='python', header=0, index_col=0)
s3 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Tim Peterson\Documents\Tom\Rocky\LRHUTTTTAUM156S.csv", encoding = "ISO-8859-1", engine='python', header=0, index_col=0)
s4 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Tim Peterson\Documents\Tom\Rocky\AUSCPIALLQINMEI.csv", encoding = "ISO-8859-1", engine='python', header=0, index_col=0)

ds1 = pd.DataFrame(s1, columns=[ 'WTISPLC'])
ds2 = pd.DataFrame(s2, columns=[ 'CCUSMA02AUM618N'])
ds3= pd.DataFrame(s3, columns=[ 'LRHUTTTTAUM156S'])
ds4=pd.DataFrame(s4, columns=[ 'AUSCPIALLQINMEI'])

print("ds1")
print(ds1)
print()
print("ds2")
print(ds2)
print()
print("ds3")
print(ds3)

mergedDf = ds1.merge(ds2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
mergedDf = mergedDf.merge(ds3, left_index=True, right_index=True)
print()
print("mergedDf")
print(mergedDf)
mergedDf = mergedDf.merge(ds4, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

and here is the output:

```
DATE               
1946-01-01     1.17
1946-02-01     1.17
1946-03-01     1.17
1946-04-01     1.27
1946-05-01     1.27
            ...
2020-11-01    40.94
2020-12-01    47.02
2021-01-01    52.00
2021-02-01    59.04
2021-03-01    62.33

[903 rows x 1 columns]

ds2
            CCUSMA02AUM618N
DATE                       
1960-01-01         0.896459
1960-02-01         0.895335
1960-03-01         0.894534
1960-04-01         0.893416
1960-05-01         0.894454
                    ...
2020-11-01         1.376790
2020-12-01         1.328943
2021-01-01         1.294495
2021-02-01         1.289795
2021-03-01         1.296970

[735 rows x 1 columns]

ds3
            LRHUTTTTAUM156S
DATE                       
01/02/1978         6.645347
01/03/1978         6.303440
01/04/1978         6.268110
01/05/1978         6.210171
01/06/1978         6.304185
                    ...
01/09/2020         6.914852
01/10/2020         6.987514
01/11/2020         6.825236
01/12/2020         6.597738
01/01/2021         6.351635

[516 rows x 1 columns]

mergedDf
            WTISPLC  CCUSMA02AUM618N  LRHUTTTTAUM156S
DATE                                                 
1979-01-01   14.850         0.875022         6.371526
1980-01-01   32.500         0.900455         6.147156
1981-01-01   38.000         0.846414         5.917194
1982-01-01   33.850         0.896675         5.983312
1983-01-01   31.190         1.017055         9.300896
1984-01-01   29.690         1.107045         9.499063
1985-01-01   25.641         1.225810         8.551031
1986-01-01   22.945         1.428609         7.805823
1987-01-01   18.656         1.516290         8.186926
1988-01-01   17.160         1.408675         7.631595
1989-01-01   17.983         1.157024         6.807849
1990-01-01   22.641         1.280209         6.112967
1991-01-01   24.959         1.283036         8.397584
1992-01-01   18.820         1.337371        10.347634
1993-01-01   19.075         1.485500        10.834346
1994-01-01   15.000         1.437000        10.569302
1995-01-01   17.990         1.309033         8.857431
1996-01-01   18.880         1.347591         8.454470
1997-01-01   25.170         1.285182         8.566446
1998-01-01   16.710         1.523038         7.865205
1999-01-01   12.470         1.574645         7.118927
2000-01-01   27.180         1.524095         6.767815
2001-01-01   29.580         1.802286         6.139834
2002-01-01   19.670         1.934264         6.913642
2003-01-01   32.940         1.716545         6.081307
2004-01-01   34.270         1.296619         5.531066
2005-01-01   46.840         1.305748         5.073780
2006-01-01   65.510         1.332955         5.162743
2007-01-01   54.570         1.277217         4.554278
2008-01-01   92.950         1.134047         4.220719
2009-01-01   41.740         1.490100         4.907489
2010-01-01   78.220         1.096000         5.265917
2011-01-01   89.420         1.003333         5.003064
2012-01-01  100.240         0.961318         5.045963
2013-01-01   94.690         0.952435         5.385983
2014-01-01   94.620         1.128584         5.934264
2015-01-01   47.220         1.236060         6.336866
2016-01-01   31.680         1.423036         6.020906
2017-01-01   52.500         1.343143         5.679780
2018-01-01   63.700         1.259082         5.501085
2019-01-01   51.380         1.401055         5.041164
2020-01-01   57.520         1.454661         5.264596
2021-01-01   52.000         1.294495         6.351635
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us an extract of the contents of a csv file, please?

Comment: WTISPLC
DATE               
1946-01-01     1.17
1946-02-01     1.17
1946-03-01     1.17
1946-04-01     1.27
1946-05-01     1.27
            ...
2020-11-01    40.94
2020-12-01    47.02
2021-01-01    52.00
2021-02-01    59.04
2021-03-01    62.33

Comment: DATE,WTISPLC1984-02-01,30.1450
1984-03-01,30.7610
1984-04-01,30.6180
1984-05-01,30.520
1984-06-01,29.9670
1984-07-01,28.7520
1984-08-01,29.250
1984-09-01,29.3110
1984-10-01,28.7650
1984-11-01,28.0980
1984-12-01,25.4290
1985-01-01,25.6410
1985-02-01,27.2710
1985-03-01,28.2380
1985-04-01,28.8050
1985-05-01,27.6230
1985-06-01,27.1430
1985-07-01,27.3290
1985-08-01,27.7550
1985-09-01,28.2890
1985-10-01,29.5380
1985-11-01,30.8130
1985-12-01,27.2280
1986-01-01,22.9450
1986-02-01,15.4420
1986-03-01,12.6180
1986-04-01,12.8470
1986-05-01,15.4440